# Query Case Sensitive with FirstOrDefault C# mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to evaluate a user and password but I got the same result if i use capital or lower case, the database is Case sensitive, but it keeps ignoring that configuration this is my code:

```
public ActionResult Login(Model.user user){

    bool isValid=false;
    var user= db.users.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.user==user.user && u.password==user.password)
    if(user!=null){
      isValid=true;          
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ - storing passwords in plaintext and rolling your own authentication system. Don't reinvent the wheel, especially not in a security-sensitive context.

Comment: Obviously i do not have the password like that, my problem is that I type Capital or lower case for user or password and it lets me access in the website, i need to make a case sensitive search @CodeCaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var query = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == user.UserName && String.Compare(u.Password, user.Password,false) == 0);
```

Working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/41ovZk).

As per OP's question (for DB based):-

```
var query = db.Users.ToList().Where(x => (string.Compare(x.UserName, user.UserName, false) == 0) && (string.Compare(x.Password, user.Password, false) == 0)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This may not work, if you're querying it on database, and database is configured "NOT TO BE CASE SENSITIVE".

Comment: If database is configured as "NOT TO BE CASE SENSITIVE" (by default SQL is NOT CASE SENSITIVE) then following error will be thrown... 

method 'boolean equals system.string system.stringcomparison ' has no supported translation to sql

Comment: @DotNetIsMyPower - I am considering entities to be object based and not SQL based, if OP need to compare just the password, he can compare username in SQL based LINQ and then convert ad compare in object based LINQ. Have updated the code.

Comment: @RahulSingh let me try this and I'll let you know how it goes,... Thanks everybody!

Comment: @DuSant - Just now noticed that you need username comparison to be case sensitive as well. Have updated the code, please check and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var result = from userlist in context.UserMasters
             where userlist.UserName.Equals(username)

// May be better (if usernames are unique):
var result = context.UserMasters.SingleOrDefault(u=>u.UserName == username);

if(result == null){
   // Did not find any user(s)
}

// If you want a case sensitive password check
if(result.UserPassword == pass){
  // The password is correct
}
else
{
      throw new Exception("Invalid password");
}

// If you don't
if(result.UserPassword.Equals(pass, StringComparison.InvariantCulture)){
  // The password is correct
}
```